# An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappdeploymentconfig(alias: Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig)

Tags: php, database, magento, magento2

I'm getting this error while I was installing magento and running a command on cmd.

the command is as follows:

`php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/mage2.4​" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="db_mage2.4" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue! Please check the PHP version, in my case php8 was causing the issue.

Try removing the php8 and install php7.2

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt update

sudo apt install php7.2

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2

sudo a2enmod php7.2

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```